# Horizontal scrollview only

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I am using unity's scrollview.
I want to disable the vertical scrollbar and i want the viewport to resize vertically depending on the content.

Too confusing to explain with word so i have created the example picture below :
[image: Horizontal Scrollview Only]

How do i achieve this properly ?